# Slower Wifi after update to kernel 3.8

Tags: 12.10, wireless, upgrade, kernel

I updated my Ubuntu 12.10 (kernel 3.7.9) to kernel 3.8 and noticed that my wifi connection from 150Mbps went to 72.2 Mbps.

Can someone help me to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED !

```
sudo  iwconfig wlan0 rate 150M fixed
```

also changed operation channel of the Wi-fi router ! Now :

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Cvetybaby"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: C8:3A:35:2A:5F:C0   
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:16482  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0
```